# Create JsonArray Response in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am stuck and need some suggestions to evaluate WSO2 ESB.

I have a request payload in JSON as below.

```
{ 
  names: 
       [ 
         {
            “name”:”niraj”
         }, 
         {
            “name=”atul”
         } 
      ]
}
```

I need to iterate $body/names/name one by one and create a JSON Array as below.

```
{ 
  resp: 
      [ 
        { 
          “name”:”niraj”, 
          “city”:”pune”
        }, 
        {
          “name”:”atul”, 
          “city”:”mumbai”
        } 
     ]
 }
```

Problem I am facing is that I am unable to create JsonArray inside foreach mediator in WSO2 ESB. I can’t see any option to define/use JsonArray in WSO2 ESB.

Kindly suggest if you have any suggestions.

I have coded the below.

```
<foreach expression="$body/Children/Children" id="f4">
<sequence>
    <filter xpath="$body/Children/_JsonReader_PS_type and $body/Children/_JsonReader_PS_type='Entity' and $body/Children/PrimaryKey='true' and $body/Children/Items/FirstName/Value ">
         <then>
            <log level="custom">
            <property name="logger" value="I am inside 8 Filter"/>
            <property expression="$body/Children/Items/FirstName/Value" name="firstName"/>
            <property expression="$body/Children/Items/LastName/Value" name="lastName"/>
            <property expression="$body/Children/Items/PersonNumber/Value" name="ssn"/>
            </log>

            <property expression="$body/Children/Items/FirstName/Value" name="firstName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="$body/Children/Items/LastName/Value" name="lastName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="$body/Children/Items/PersonNumber/Value" name="ssn" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{
                        "First Name" : "$1",
                        "Last Name" : "$2",
                        "SSN" : "$3"
            }</format>

            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('firstName')"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('lastName')"/>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ssn')"/>
            </args>
            </payloadFactory>

            <log>
            <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="JSON-Payload"/>
            </log>
         </then>
         <else/>
    </filter>
</sequence>
</foreach>
```

Thanks!

Comment: in the sample response shared, for the additional city property, do you need to make any dss or backend call or just update the request payload using payload factory mediator?

Comment: It is just an sample. I have a requirement where I have requirement in which parent node has 15 children nodes. I need to check if each next children node exists, if it does, I need to get the value out inside one of them and then create a JSONObject linked with name and add it to JsonArray.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you include that as well?

Comment: I have updated with implementation done. Any suggestions to generate JsobObject and load them to JsonArray without using ClassMediator.